# Why Chrome React developer Tools is still red after deployed react app to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, google-chrome-extension, web-deployment, react-devtools

[image]

I have deployed a react app to Heroku, But after I open the Heroku link, the chrome react developer tool is still red, which means it is still under development? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because you have deployed the development version of the app.
There is a simple fix for that.

1. Go to your app's dashboard in heroku
2. Click settings
3. scroll down to Buildpacks
4. Add this https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git
5. save and then deploy your app again and it will be alright

hope it works